# Flycheck could not find file under load-path

Tags: init-file, flycheck, load-path

I have some elips `*.el` file in my `~/.emacs.d/gman/` folder, e.g. `smart-inputp-methods.el`. This folder is added to my load path at the beginning of `.emacs` file:

```el
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/gman")
```

Leter I importing it:

```el
(require 'smart-input-methods)
```

Functions defined there successfully loaded, however **Flycheck** reports me error on that line, that file could not be found:

> Cannot open load file: no such file or directory, smart-input-methods

This is quite annoying, how can I fix that?

Comment: The library for `flycheck` on Github does not have a file named `smart-input-methods.el`  Why do you believe this is a valid file name?  https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck  Googling for `"smart-input-methods"` yields no results except for this particular thread -- which could mean that the file may not exist except in your own setup.  If you created `smart-input-methods.el` for your own purposes, then you will need to put `(provide 'smart-input-methods)` at the bottom of the file in order to be able to use `require` later on.

Comment: @lawlist He said flycheck is reporting "no such file" on that line, because that is what flycheck does (point out errors in lisp files), he's not saying that file is part of flycheck. He is asking why this error is being triggered even though the file is on his `load-path`. On a separate note, that error is caused when a file isn't found, not when a file is missing the `provide` statement (that is a different error).

Comment: @lawlist, **Malabarba** is right,  I do have `provide` statement in my file. This script modifies internal Emacs keyboard layout to correspond with apple keyboard (when Russian input method selected). By the way, this error message also occurs when I `require` something installed from MELPA.

Comment: Thank you both for helping to correct me -- I am always grateful to learn new aspects of Emacs.

Comment: Could it be because there is no actually corresponding function in `smart-input-methods.el`? There is runnable code only, e.g. input method is being modified when file evaluated, I could share the code if needed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flycheck does simply not use your `load-path` for checking.  By default, it always checks files in a clean environment, using only the built-in `load-path` of Emacs.  IOW, Flycheck always checks in `emacs -Q`.

To make your custom code visible to Flycheck, you can either explicitly add all directories to `flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path` as well, or set `flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path` to `inherit`.  In the latter case, Flycheck will automatically use your entire `load-path` when checking files.

When you edit `user-init-file` or files inside `user-emacs-directory`, Flycheck automatically adds ELPA packages to `load-path`, though.

Comment: Is there a way to make flycheck add the elpa packages from any directory?

Comment: @Malabarba `flycheck-emacs-lisp-initialize-packages` and `flycheck-emacs-lisp-package-user-dir`

Comment: set `flycheck-emacs-lisp-load-path` to `inherit`, and this is solved issue, many thanks!